# Emulator throws exception (android studio) when function is called

Tags: java, android, function, android-studio, save

I'm coding a game on android studio and it works fine, but it started crashing when i moved a function in another class.

I did it so I could use it everywhere by having it only once and not copy pasting on every class I need to use it.

I checked on google how to solve this problem but nothing is working, the error is with "getExternalFilesDir" or "openFileOutput" returning null i think.

Here is the class with two functions (doing basically the same thing) but that I can't use.

```
import android.media.MediaScannerConnection;
import android.util.Log;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class WriteUserData extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    public void writeToFile(String data, String file) {
        try {
            OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(file + ".txt", MODE_PRIVATE));
            outputStreamWriter.write(data);
            outputStreamWriter.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
        }
    }

    public void saveFile(String fileName, String addText){
        try {
            // Creates a file in the primary external storage space of the
            // current application.
            // If the file does not exists, it is created.
            File newFile = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null), fileName + ".txt");
            if (!newFile.exists())
                newFile.createNewFile();

            // Adds a line to the file
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newFile, true /*append*/));
            writer.write(addText);
            writer.close();
            // Refresh the data so it can seen when the device is plugged in a
            // computer. You may have to unplug and replug the device to see the
            // latest changes. This is not necessary if the user should not modify
            // the files.
            MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                    new String[]{newFile.toString()},
                    null,
                    null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ReadWriteFile", "Error while trying to add text in " + fileName + ".txt");
        }
    }

}
```

and there is the place where i try to call the functions but crashes the emulator (I removed some code 'import') so it is easier for you to understand.

```
    private boolean showStats = true;
    private final static long Interval = 30;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private int flashDisplay = 0;

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_over);

        // change game over screen on click
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(showStats){
                            getStats();
                        }
                        flashDisplay++;
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 0, Interval);
    }

    private static void bring(){
        WriteUserData saveScore = new WriteUserData();
        saveScore.saveFile("userdata", "ThisTextWork");
        saveScore.writeToFile("ThisTextWorkToo", "config");
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private void getStats(){
        bring();
    }
}
```

This is the error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.FileOutputStream android.content.Context.openFileOutput(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
> Blockquote

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The entire error is on there: https://hasteb.in/pokefeki.sql

Comment: You need the error here. Not necessarily the full stacktrace, but your Question must be self contained.

Comment: done, i think thats what you meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how activities work.

```
public class WriteUserData extends AppCompatActivity {
```

You're extending an Activity class, so `WriteUserData` is also an activity. In that case, it should be named as such - `WriteUserDataActivity`.

However, looking at what you're doing here:

```
WriteUserData saveScore = new WriteUserData();
```

This is not how you're supposed to use an activity. It should be created with an Intent and `startActivity()`, see here:

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity

What you wanted to do is move the logic for opening a file in a separate class to avoid code duplication. That's great, but it should **not** be done with an activity. Instead, you should use a Utils/Helper class. Your class shouldn't extend anything and should have a private constructor:

```
public class WriteUserDataUtils { 
    private WriteUserDataUtils() { 
        // utils classes shouldn't be instanced
    }
    ... 
}
```

After that, change the methods inside it to be `static`:

```
public static void writeToFile(String data, String file) {
    ...
}

public static void saveFile(String fileName, String addText) {
    ...
}
```

Finally, the reason you extended an `Activity` is that you needed `Context` for some things (e.g. opening a file stream). This can easily be fixed by passing it as a parameter:

```
public static void writeToFile(String data, String file, Context context) {
    OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput(file + ".txt", MODE_PRIVATE));
    ...
}

public static void saveFile(String fileName, String addText, Context context){
    try {
        File newFile = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), fileName + ".txt");
    ...
}
```

After you refactored it into a utils class, you can call it from the activity like this:

```
private static void bring(){
    WriteUserDataUtils.saveFile("userdata", "ThisTextWork", this);
    WriteUserDataUtils.writeToFile("ThisTextWorkToo", "aconfig", this);
}
```

Let me know if you need any further clarification.

Comment: Thank you, it is working perfectly, i like let you know (or if anyone has the same problem) that "bring()" should not be static:```private void bring(){
    WriteUserDataUtils.saveFile("userdata", "ThisTextWork", this);
    WriteUserDataUtils.writeToFile("ThisTextWorkToo", "aconfig", this);
}```